# call a function when component visibility changes

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Pretty simple thing but I am stuck.

**Question:** I want to call a function when the visibility of my component changes so I can do some clean up.

I have tried using the FlexEvents `FlexEvent.HIDE` and `FlexEvent.SHOW` and specified the function to call in my mxml header

```
show="onShow(event)"
```

---

```
private function onShow(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    trace("********** onShow***********");
}
```

---

That didn't work. I then tried adding various eventListeners but that didn't work, Am I using listening for the wrong events?

```
addEventListener(FlexEvent.SHOW, onShow, false, 0, true);
addEventListener(FlexEvent.STATE_CHANGE_COMPLETE, onHide, false, 0, true);
```

---

And finally I tried overriding the setter for `visible` but that threw errors

```
        override public function set visible(value:Boolean):void
        {
            super.visible = value;
            visible = value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right when using `FlexEvent.HIDE` and `FlexEvent.SHOW` but I don't know why you didn't get what you want. Take this simple example where a button hide a second one and when this last is hidden it disable the first one. A third button show the second one which when it is visible enable the first button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function button_02_hideHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                button_01.enabled = false;
            }

            protected function button_01_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                button_02.visible = false;
            }

            protected function button_03_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                button_02.visible = true;
            }

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                button_02.addEventListener(FlexEvent.SHOW, function(e:FlexEvent){

                    button_01.enabled = true;

                })

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button id="button_01" x="68" y="93" label="Button 01" click="button_01_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="button_02" x="170" y="93" label="Button 02" hide="button_02_hideHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="button_03" x="276" y="93" label="Button 03" click="button_03_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: thanks for the reality check. This is a legacy project I inherited and I am still getting a sense of what is going on. Turns out that instead of the visibility of the component I was working with being toggled, it was a component overlaying it - so the visibility of the one I was concerned about was never changing. Wasted a good hour on that. Arrrgh..